# How can I smart sort my table content and add style inside MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, distinct, group-concat, find-in-set

table `orders`:

```
+----+-------+
| id | order |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    21 |
|  2 |    23 |
|  3 |    22 |
+----+-------+
```

table `products`:

```
+----+--------+-----------+----------+
| id |  Name  | Category  | order_id |
+----+--------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Chair  | Furniture |       21 |
|  2 | Cat    | Animals   |       21 |
|  3 | Dog    | Animals   |       22 |
|  4 | Table  | Furniture |       22 |
|  5 | Red    | Colors    |       23 |
|  6 | Monkey | Animals   |       23 |
|  7 | Blue   | Colors    |       22 |
|  8 | Car    | Transport |       22 |
+----+--------+-----------+----------+



$orders = $db->query('SELECT *
GROUP_CONCAT(products.Name SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS products,
   FROM orders
   LEFT JOIN products ON orders.order=products.order_id
   GROUP BY orders.id ASC 
   ORDER BY orders.id ASC
')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is my result:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align:top
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>products</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Chair<br>Cat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Red<br>Monkey</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Table<br>Car<br>Blue<br>Dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is: I want to sort the products by a specific category order:

```
Colors
Animals
Furniture
Transport
```

and add a category related color to each product. So as a result it should look like this:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align:top
}

.circle {
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
      -moz-border-radius: 25px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      display:inline-block
    }
    
.animals{
    background:#b8c7ce}
.colors{
    background:#aa787b}
.furniture{
    background:rgb(229, 117, 162)}
    .transport{
    background:rgb(101, 201, 148);}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>products</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><div class="circle animals"></div>Cat(Animals)<br><div class="circle furniture"></div>Chair(Furniture)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><div class="circle colors"></div>Red (Colors)<br><div class="circle animals"></div>Monkey(Animals)</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><div class="circle colors"></div>Blue(Colors)<br><div class="circle animals"></div>Dog(Animals)<br><div class="circle furniture"></div>Table (Furniture)<br><div class="circle transport"></div>Car(Transport)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So I changed my code to:

```
    $orders = $db->query('SELECT *
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("<div class="circle,
     IF(products.Category=="Animals","animals")"
     IF(products.Category=="Furniture","furniture")"
     IF(products.Category=="Transport","transport")"
     IF(products.Category=="Colors","colors")"</div>"
   ,products,Name,"(",products.Category,")") SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS products,
     FROM orders
     LEFT JOIN products ON orders.order=products.order_id
     GROUP BY orders.id ASC 
     ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(products.Category,"Colors,Animals,Furniture,Transport") ASC
    ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But the sorting is not working properly and I get an error message:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '",
>   IF(products.Category=="Animals","animals")"...

Comment: I think you should be generating the HTML in your PHP code, not from MySQL.  Generally try to avoid presentation layer stuff from MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am looking for a solution in mySQL

Comment: Your quotes are mis-matched in the concat statement. Use single quotes inside the html portions of the string. But, as @TimBiegeleisen suggests, it's better to do the formatting in the PHP code instead of the MySQL code, and a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: I'm very curious why you are doing this in MySQL. Care to explain your reasons?

Comment: @rlanvin Because the result of the query is going directly into a json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $orders = $db->query('SELECT *
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("<div class=\'circle ",
       CASE
           WHEN products.Category = "Animals" THEN "animals"
           WHEN products.Category = "Transport" THEN "transport"
           WHEN products.Category = "Furniture" THEN "furniture"
           WHEN products.Category = "Colors" THEN "colors"
           ELSE ""
       END,"\'</div>"
     ,products,Name,"(",products.Category,")")
     ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(products.Category,"Colors,Animals,Furniture,Transport") ASC
     SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS products,
     FROM orders
     LEFT JOIN products ON orders.order=products.order_id
     GROUP BY orders.id ASC 
    ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

The equals operator has a single '='